# MongoDB Aggregation not updating my collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to run an aggregation query in Mongo using their nodejs driver, that takes some of my fields and adds/finds averages etc. I built the aggregation in Mongo Cloud and exported it to node, but when I run the code, I get the following responses from Mongo:

> this.res could not be serialized.

> steps.update_mongo.res:null

Here's the code (history field is an array of objects):

```
const agg = [
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'avgGrowth': {
        '$ceil': {
          '$avg': '$history.growth'
        }
      }, 
      'avgDecline': {
        '$ceil': {
          '$avg': '$history.decline'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$merge': {
      'into': {'db':'mydb', 'coll':'test'},
      'on': '$_id'
      },
  }
];

const coll = await db.collection('test');

this.res = await coll.aggregate(agg, async(cmdErr, result) => {
  await assert.equal(null, cmdErr);
});
```

Comment: Why not simply `{ $avg: "$history.growth" }`?

Comment: Good point, I can simplify. Thank you. That said, that doesn't fix the problem of not being able to send the data to Mongo, which seems to be where my issue is.

Comment: `aggregate` is just a **query** function - unless you use `$out` or `$merge` stage in the end. You can use aggregation pipeline also in [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline) command, however your sample code is a simple query, i.e. read operation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @WernfriedDomscheit - I had assumed that $addFields would add the fields to my document, is that incorrect?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've added in my merge query now and still getting the same response from MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.res = await coll.aggregate(agg, async(cmdErr, result) => {
  await assert.equal(null, cmdErr);
});
```

Is an incorrect syntax. You either provide a callback OR use await, not both.

Try using is as follow :

```
this.res = await coll.aggregate(agg);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! When I do that, I get the following error: "this.res contains [Circular] reference(s) that were filtered out.", I'm not sure where the circular reference is though.

Comment: Try to use it as follow then : await coll.aggregate(agg).exec()